# Convert an array of string to an array of BigDecimals

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to convert a String[] to BigDecimal[] but i'm getting java.lang.NumberFormatException

this is my code

```
BigDecimal montanttt[] = new BigDecimal[montantt.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < montantt.length; i++) {
            montanttt[i] = new BigDecimal(montantt[i]);
            System.out.println(montanttt[i]);
        }
```

Comment: What is the content of `montantt`?

Comment: `String[] montantt = request.getParameterValues("montant");`

Comment: What is the content of `request.getParameterValues("montant");`?

Comment: I think he means what is the actual string content. For example ['James', 'Harry', '2'].

Comment: Please also give your variables better names.. Now it so easy to confuse `montanttt` and `montantt`

Comment: The confusing variable names aside, what is your input? Probably you have something that is not a number in that `montatt` (one t) array.

Comment: my inputs are ['0.50','0.20']

Comment: @WassimAbbas if they are like `'0.20'` (not `0.20`) you should remove quotations first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for exception using try/catch in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < montantt.length; i++) {
    try {
        montanttt[i] = new BigDecimal(montantt[i]);
        System.out.println(montanttt[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while parsing: " + montantt[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compact solution on Java 8 is here.

```
Arrays.stream(montantt).map(s -> {
        try { 
            return new BigDecimal(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
}).toArray(BigDecimal[]::new);
```

You will get `NumberFormatException` if `String` cannot be converted to `BigDecimal`. But you can return some constant if the exception was thrown, for example `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

---

It works fine for your input `["0.50","0.20"]`.

Comment: If `montantt` contains invalid strings, that won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear all chars that are not part of number and normalize decimal point before parsing, like:

```
String normalized = montantt[i].replace(",", ".").replaceAll("[^-.0-9eE]", "");
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(normalized);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
BigDecimal montanttt[] = new BigDecimal[montantt.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < montantt.length; i++) {
        try {
         montanttt[i] =BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(montantt[i]))
        System.out.println(montanttt[i]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    }
```